# Suggest an OCR Library for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ocr, scanning

I want to make an offline iPhone application that can grab text from a picture. Can anyone suggest the best library which I can use. I heard ZBAR and ZXING can be used only for barcode reading. Is there any other OCR Libraries for iOS to read text from images. I expect your valuable suggestions as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: why this question off-topic?. Isn't it related to iOS application development ? Im not clear with stack overflow rules. Please anyone tell me how this question is under off-topic.

Comment: I know it's frustrating. They are doing their job, however silly it may seem.

Comment: 90% of scanners on appstore are based on Tesseract. If the image has noise or different background it wont work. But this app seem to work no matter what https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ocr-scan-text-from-camera/id1163617952?l=nb&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: There is also an other OCR framework called SwiftOCR which claims it has better accuracy and low CPU usage than Tesseract: https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currenlty offline `OCR` is possible only with `Tesseract`

You can get source code [here](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios)

[Here](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/compile-tesseract-for-ios-sdk-6-0/) is the good tutorial about how to use `Tesseract`

Also you can perform `OCR` on multiple language. You can dowlnoad other language trained data [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)

Comment: But I heard it is very slow and also less accurate. Is there any other  perfect libraries..?

Comment: also you would have to compile the lib by yourself for arm64 since i only i see libs for armv6 and amrv7... but it should not be that hard

Comment: @Vaisakh It is not slow and also not so much fast. It is depending on how you are processing the image. Its speed totally depend on iPhone device processing speed.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Do you know any tutorials that tells how to improve accuracy of Tesseract ? If you have any suggestion please help me.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre it's fairly expensive on the CPU to get accurate results. It gets more expensive with the more languages you add on. Even running the OCR on the medium setting on an iPhone 6s, the CPU runs up to 99% usage easily. It's also not very accurate per say. Many of the edge cases for paragraph formatting and fonts you have to manually configure in code.

Comment: It would be great to find a better solution rather a library that wasn't built for mobile usage in the first place.

Comment: @TheCodingArt agree with you. But as per research no other offline OCR was available that time. If you have any OCR available please suggest us.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look [here](http://www.visionobjects.com/en/myscript/language-offering/description/). They offer a large variation of language they can detect and i heard only the best from their framework.

You can also test the framework live: [live demo](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/home.html;jsessionid=1549v5878uw161aramceh1hljb?locale=de_DE#portal)

Unfortunately i think it is very expensive to use this framework. But if you want an A1(all my Breaking Bad fans ;-)) framework this might be your best shot.

Comment: And also its required network. Offline OCR is not possible with this.

Comment: Ya. But I want to make and offline Application. So this will not be useful.

Comment: then you really should go with tesseract... you can get really good results if your handwriting/letters/numbers to recognize are near/similar to printed ones

Comment: @dehlen Do you have any good suggestion to improve accuracy in tesseract ? I am getting very very poor response.